# How to name foreign key constraints in JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How to name foreign key constraints in JPA, the following is a foreign key constraint from `foos` table which points to `users` table via `foos.user_id`

```
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists foos 
       add constraint FKff5wc10svmgvwumia2rsfaud6 
       foreign key (user_id) 
       references users
```